# Where is determined that the file has PHP code in it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading "Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, and CSS: A Step-by-Step Guide to Creating Dynamic Websites" 4th edition. I came across request-response procedure. After fetch page, the data should be sent to web browser and the web browser should send the data to web server after it detects PHP in it. Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: PHP is more like the toaster than the bread in that analogy.

Comment: PHP is a bit like a toaster, when you order toast from a cafe, you never see the bread, or the toaster, you [the browser] will only ever see the toast, but the server [the server] takes the bread and runs it through the toaster to make toast out of it, before passing the completed [toasted] toast back to you, the browser.

Comment: @Quentin unfortunately by mere seconds I missed the 5minute cut off for comment edits , the analogy was that the browser never sees the base product, which is the bread, only the output product, which is the toast.

Comment: Having the server run PHP code that it got from the client would be a security nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong.

The browser will never detect PHP in a page. PHP is executed by the server and the output of the PHP program is sent to the browser. The browser only sees HTML (or an image, or whatever else you want the PHP to output).

Answer (score 0):

The web browser doesn't care what the server is running. It talks HTTP to the server, and the server talks HTTP back. The server's configuration is what tells the server that a URL should be routed to a particular PHP script.